# Laravel how to get current Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have the following in my Routes.php:

```
Route::get('cat/{cat}', ['as' => 'cat', 'uses' => 'CatController@get']);
```

I want to check in my sidebar.blade.php file if any of the views returned from the Controller function matches the current page.

`{cat}` could be either a,b,c,d,f or e.
The sidebar consists of 6 images.
If for example the route is `cat/a` the image of tis route should be changed.

People suggested `Route::current()->getName()` but this only returns `cat` and not /a, /b, /c, etc. Also some other functions are only returning `cat/` and nothing after that

Comment: Did you try `Route::currentRouteName()`?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin The current route's name will be `cat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Request::is('cat/a')`.

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but I had to change Route to Request.

Comment: @PoTTii My bad, `Request` it is! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `{cat}` part with this:

```
$cat = Request::route()->getParameter('cat');
```

And the route with:

```
$route = Route::currentRouteName();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('cat/{cat}', ['as' => 'cat', 'uses' => 'CatController@get'])->name('name-your-route');
```

In view.blade.php:

```
@if(request()->routeIS('name-your-route'))

@endif
```